# The tex file suddenly does not work

Tags: compiling, chemfig

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\title{mechanism}
\maketitle

\newpage

\begin{center}
\section*{addition of \ce{HX} to alkene}    
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{-[:-60]C(-[:240])=_[@{a1}]C(-[:60])(-[:-60])}
    \arrow{0}[,0]\+
    \chemfig{@{a2}H-_[@{a3}]@{b1}X@{z}}
    \arrow(@{z}--[yshift=5pt]){->[][][2pt]}
    \chemfig{-C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90])-\chemabove{C}{\oplus}(-[:-90])(-)}
    \arrow{0}[,0]\+
    \chemfig{\charge{180=\:}{X}\chemright{X}{\ominus}}
    \schemestop
    \chemmove{\draw(a1)..controls +(100:5mm) and +(145:5mm)..(a2);\draw(a3)..controls +(100:5mm) and +(145:5mm).. (b1):}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

My TeX file suddenly cannot compile into a PDF file. Can anyone help me fix it?

Comment: The colon in `(b1):}` should be a semicolon. No chance this has ever worked.

Answer (score 1):

There was a ":" instead of ";" at the end of the last line of the \draw command.

To find errors, disable "%" the last line you typed before the error appeared, and compile. If there are no errors, the previous error is on the disabled line "%"

place each \draw command on separate lines for easy viewing and understanding.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
    
    \title{mechanism}
    \maketitle
    
    \newpage
    
    \begin{center}
        \section*{addition of \ce{HX} to alkene}    
    \end{center}
    
    \begin{center}
        \schemestart
        \chemfig{-[:-60]C(-[:240])=_[@{a1}]C(-[:60])(-[:-60])}
        \arrow{0}[,0]\+
        \chemfig{@{a2}H-[@{a3}]@{b1}X@{z}}
        \arrow(@{z}--[yshift=5pt]){->[][][2pt]}
        \chemfig{-C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90])-\chemabove{C}{\oplus}(-[:-90])(-)}
        \arrow{0}[,0]\+
        \chemfig{\charge{180=\:}{X}\chemright{X}{\ominus}}
        \schemestop
        \chemmove{
            \draw(a1)..controls +(100:5mm) and +(145:5mm)..(a2);
            \draw(a3)..controls +(100:5mm) and +(145:5mm).. (b1);
        }
    \end{center}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didnt notice I type a :